# Open Single Repeating Div on Click

Tags: jquery

I have a list of repeating items (houses/properties) that is being generated by a web service. Inside the `<li>` I have inserted a link and beneath each `<li>` there is a `<div>` that I want to show when the button is clicked.

All the divs with the class of mortgage-calc are opening and I only want the one related to the property to open. This is my code:

```
jQuery('.mortgage-calc').hide();
jQuery('.mc-btn').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); /* to stop null-link jumping to top  */
    jQuery('.mortgage-calc').slideToggle();
});
```

I have tried using .next(), .each(), and .find() with no luck so would appreciate some help please.

Comment: Can include example `html` at Question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. Because the link you are clicking is inside of the `<li>` tag, you need to go up to that parent element and then traverse the tree downwards. You can use the `.closest` command to get up to the `<li>` then use `.find` or `.next` to get to the `<div>` to toggle the hidden content. I chose `.next` since you know the structure will always be the same.

```
jQuery('.mortgage-calc').hide();
jQuery('.mc-btn').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); /* to stop null-link jumping to top  */
    jQuery(this).closest('li').next('.mortgage-calc').slideToggle();
});
```

Here is a fiddle with what I believe to be your HTML structure and working code. [Fiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dhj57omb/)

Comment: Thanks Lance, that does it exactly. Thanks for the reminder of going up the tree first!

Answer (score 1):

if li has class mc-btn  .. use this

```
jQuery('.mortgage-calc').hide();
jQuery('.mc-btn').click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); /* to stop null-link jumping to top  */
    jQuery('.mortgage-calc').hide();
    $(this).find('.mortgage-calc').slideToggle();
});
```

if you have button inside each li with  mc-btn class

```
jQuery('.mortgage-calc').hide();
    jQuery('.mc-btn').click( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); /* to stop null-link jumping to top  */
        jQuery('.mortgage-calc').hide();
        $(this).closest('li').find('.mortgage-calc').slideToggle();
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed-Yousef, not working though. It was the second option so thanks for trying both. Lance's solution works below.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.mortgage-calc').hide();
    jQuery('.mc-btn').click( function(e) {
       e.preventDefault(); /* to stop null-link jumping to top  */
       $(this).children(".mortgage-calc").slideToggle();
    });
})
```